# How to use IDE keymap in GoLand Terminal

Tags: jetbrains-ide, goland

Until recently I was able to use keymaps such as `Ctrl`+`Right` to move the caret to the next word in my Bash Terminals embedded in GoLand on Ubuntu 18.04. I'm not sure what has changed but these no longer work. Now if I try to use the example shortcut it just types `C`. What settings do I need to change to get this to work? I have tried this with both "Tools>Terminal>Override IDE shortcuts" checked and unchecked.

Comment: What OS do you use?

Comment: @artspb sorry should have mentioned that, I'm on Ubuntu 18.04. I've added this to the main post now.

Comment: I can't find a similar open issue so it's worth reporting here https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA Please don't forget to specify versions of the OS and GoLand. Also, it might make sense to try the latest version before reporting a bug https://www.jetbrains.com/go/nextversion/

Comment: @artspb I have fixed this now. Turns out it wasn't an IDE problem it was an issue with my bash configuration, but this makes me wonder: what does "Settings>Tools>Terminal>Override IDE shortcuts" actually do? It doesn't seem to me as if it is doing anything.

Comment: There are certain IDE shortcuts that clash with terminal ones, e.g. Ctrl+E. This option helps to control who should handle them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this was not an IDE issue. Whilst trying to add support for using `Ctrl` + `Backspace` for deleting words, I had created a `~/.inputrc` file which was overriding my `/etc/inputrc` file. Deleting this file fixed the problem.